# While installing material ui there is copy of package.json create automatically

Tags: reactjs

While installing Material UI I don't understand if there is another `package.json` and `package.lock.json` installed can anyone help me out with this?

I want to install Material UI in a way so that no additional copy of `package.json` is created.

Comment: Can you provide your structure folder image before and after you install mui?

Comment: Can u please help I can't find the image upload option